# Taking access rights away from standard user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, standard-user

I have two accounts on my Windows 7 machine, one administrator, another standard.

Once I was logged in as a standard user, and I wanted to have a look at administrators desktop, so I typed in the administrators password and gained access.

Now my password is saved for this folder and can be accessed anytime by standard user even after restart/shutdown/etc.

How do I block all or a single administrator's folder again?

Answer (score 5):

- Log in as the standard user
- Go to the Control Panel.
- Ensure that **View by** is set to **Large Icons**
- Click the **Credential Manager** icon
  You should see all stored passwords listed and they can be cleared individually.

Note that there is a shortcut to the credential manager: just paste this into the address bar and hit enter: *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager*